# How to do a find iterating in a array field

Tags: mongodb, express

Hi i have a expressjs app using mongodb.

At first i find a tv by id on my "tvs" collection, i get it but now i want to find all user info from other collection "users".

This is my JSON for each collection:

**tvs**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5203af83396d285ea2ecff8f"),
  "brand" : "LG",
  "comments" : [{
      "user" : ObjectId("521dc636eda03d0f9cab3568"),
      "text" : "Sold!"
    }, {
      "user" : ObjectId("521b2785eda03d0f9cab3566"),
      "text" : "Nice TV"
    }],
  "model" : "47LS5600",
  "price" : 499.0
}
```

**users**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("521b2785eda03d0f9cab3566"),
  "name" : {
    "first" : "Ruben",
    "last" : "Montes"
  }
}
```

And this is my code

```
var tvs = db.collection("tvs");
var users = db.collection("users");

exports.findById = function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    tvs.findOne({'_id': new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function (err, tv) {
        users.find( { _id : tv.comments.user_id }).toArray(function (err, items) {
            res.send( { tv: tv, users: items } );
        }); 

    })
}
```

I need to know how to iterate the comments array from tvs collection to get the the info user that post a comment

```
users.find( { _id : tv.comments.user_id })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a bit more logic to efficiently grab the users as a batch using the `$in` operator.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb')
    , MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , Server = require('mongodb').Server;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var tvs = db.collection('tvs');
    var users = db.collection('users');

    var userNames = {};
    var tvId = new mongodb.ObjectID("5203af83396d285ea2ecff8f"); // hard-code

    // find a TV
    tvs.findOne({ _id : tvId }, function (err, tv) {
        var allUserIds = [];
        if (tv && tv.comments) {
            // build a list of all user IDs used in comments
            // this doesn't filter duplicates right now
            allUserIds = tv.comments.map(function (comment) {
                return comment.user;
            });
        }

        // using the list of UserIds, grab all of them ...,
        // and just return the name
        users.find({_id: { $in: allUserIds }}, { name: 1 })
            .toArray(function (err, users_list) {
                // if we got some
                if (users_list && users_list.length > 0) {
                    for(var i= 0, len = users_list.length; i < len ; i++ ) {
                        userNames[users_list[i]._id] = users_list[i].name;
                    }
                    console.log("All comments ========");
                    // now all the usernames are indexed in userNames by Id
                    for(var i= 0, len = tv.comments.length; i < len ; i++ ) {
                         // swap id for name
                        tv.comments[i].user = userNames[tv.comments[i].user];
                        console.log(tv.comments[i]);
                    }
                    db.close();   // done with everything for this demo
                }
            });
    });
});
```

I've used `find` and `$in` with an array of all `userIds` found in the comments for a single "tv". By using `$in`, it significantly reduces the number of calls needed to MongoDB to fetch single `User` documents. Also, using the second parameter of `find`, I've reduced the returned fields to just be `name`.

FYI -- I did simplify your structure to just be 'name' rather than 'first' and 'last'. You certainly can change it to match your exact needs.